# Build menu through Route::group in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 `Route::group` and each one has a couple of `routes`. For example:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'/guest', 'middleware'=>'guest'], function()
{
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'Login to the site', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@login']);
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'Register', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@register']);
    Route::get('restore', ['as' => 'Restore the password', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@restore']);
});


Route::group(['prefix'=>'/admin', 'middleware'=>'auth', function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'Home Page', 'uses' => 'AdminController@users']);
    Route::get('/users', ['as' => 'Users', 'uses' => 'AdminController@users']);
});
```

So, I would like automatically to build a menu using the current prefix of `Route::group`. If user is authenticated Laravel should display the menu list like this:

```
<li><a href="/admin/dashboard">Home Page</a></li>
<li><a href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>
```

but if user is just guest, in this case my menu should be like this:

```
<li><a href="/guest/login">Login to the site</a></li>
<li><a href="/guest/register">Register</a></li>
```

If you look through the second guest menu, you will see that `menu for Restoring password` was missed. Yes, I would like sometimes do not display some menus.

**Basically, I have a 2 questions:**

1. Find the routes which belong to the current Route group and build a
   menu.
2. Don't display any routes in menu, adding some option to them.

Comment: Why complicate things so much, for something so simple? Why not just check if the user is logged in and have the navigation items as plain html with the URLs created with the `route` helper function? If there were a lot of routes I would understand the benefit of having the menu generated dynamically, but in this case it's just overkill.

Comment: @Bogdan, believe I have 5 `route::group` and each of them have 5-7 routes, That's why I am looking for comfortable way. Otherwise I should build manually

Comment: Are these routes from the groups going to change frequently or at all? Because otherwise it's the same argument, you're creating overhead where it isn't needed. Don't take it the wrong way, I'm just trying to give the best advice I can, so that's why I'm asking about the reasoning behind your approach.

Comment: Well, let me tell you about this project. Admin, instructor and student can join to this project. And each of them I created `route::group`. Middleware checks each user and the user with status `admin` must not to access and to see another user's menu with status `instructor`  About middleware I haven't any problem. I just want to bring suitable menus to each status(`admin`, `instructor`, `student`) of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added "@" in alias for some routes which I want to hide.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'/guest', 'middleware'=>'guest'], function()
{
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'Login to the site', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@login']);
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'Register', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@register']);
    Route::get('restore', ['as' => 'Restore the password@hide', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@restore']);
});
```

Then in view I added this code:

```
foreach( Route::getRoutes() as $route){
    $data = explode('@', $route->getName());

    if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix() == $route->getPrefix() && @$data[1] == "" ){
        echo '<li><a href="'.$route->getPath() .'">'.$data[0].'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Now, I successfully displayed all routers of current `route::group` and hide some routes adding `@` to the alias. In example it is `Restore the password@hide`

Comment: Very nice solution of identifying the grouped routes via they prefix.

Comment: @Bogdan, is there any way to get all routes by method `GET` as I used?

Comment: Yes, just add this to your condition: `in_array('GET', $route->getMethods())`.

Answer (score 3):

*Route groups are transient and their only use is to allow the router to populate in bulk the specific attributes (prefixes, namespaces, etc) of the routes that are in them.*

When you register a group, the attributes you pass to it are added to the routes that are defined inside the group, then the group is deleted. So the group exists within the router only while the `Route::group` method is being executed.

All that means that you **can't** get any group information, in your route closure or controller method in order to get the routes inside.

---

Since you say that you have 3 types of users, then you should probably have a way to get the user type of the authenticated user, with something like `Auth::user()->type` (which would return one of these values `admin`, `instructor`, `student`). Also, you should be able to use `Auth::guest()` to determine if a user is not logged in.

So you can just do the following to handle menu generation (the code below assumes that the `$user` variable contains the model from `Auth::user()`):

```php
<ul>
    @if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="/guest/login">Login to the site</a></li>
        <li><a href="/guest/register">Register</a></li>
    @else
        @if ($user->type == 'admin')
            <li><a href="/admin/dashboard">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>
            ...
       @elseif ($user->type == 'instructor')
            <li><a href="/instructor/dashboard">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/instructor/students">Students</a></li>
            ...
       @elseif ($user->type == 'student')
            <li><a href="/student/dashboard">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/student/lessons">Lessons</a></li>
            ...
       @endif
    @endif
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for helping. Actually It was my method also :)  Now I thought the way and added an answer by myself.